# Accessing remote linux server's localhost:8080 from windows desktop

Tags: linux, ssh, localhost, spagobi

I am a complete beginner with Linux. I have ssh access (I think that's what it is) to a linux server. I have a program called SpagoBI installed on the server, and it needs to be accessed through localhost:8080 in a browser. I have changed the xml file that points to localhost to the ip of the server but I still can't access it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to access the localhost through the ip?

Answer (score 1):

With SpagoBI configured to answer on localhost (the default), you can use Putty on Windows create an SSH tunnel from your local system to the SpagoBI system. If you were to redirect local 8080 (of your local system)  to 8080 of the SpagoBI system, then you could access the remote SpagoBI server like this http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI while the SSH tunnel is up.

Now... to configure the SpagoBI server correctly so that it answers on a specific FQDNS... you'll need to modify the Tomcat server.xml

Go to the Tomcat config directory and edit server.xml. These are two entries you'll need to modify. Then restart tomcat and try to access SpagoBI using the FQDNS and URL.

```
<Environment name="spagobi_service_url" type="java.lang.String" value="http://spagobi.example.com:8080/SpagoBI"/>
<Environment name="spagobi_host_url" type="java.lang.String" value="http://spagobi.example.com:8080"/>
```

After restart, try accessing SpagoBI  like   http://spagobi.example.com:8080/SpagoBI

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not all that familiar with servers, so this is all new to me. Could you explain how to do the SSH tunnel with Putty?

Comment: Creating a tunnel seems about right given the original question. Use Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels and a proper guide. In fact.. it's the only way if you want to use 'localhost' in the browser apart from changing localhost to the IP Address (another option). See: 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'. For the FQDN method too..  don't forget to add the IP Address and domain (spagobi.example.com) to the hosts file if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood. Do you write "localhost:8080" on your remote windows machine? If so, you should write the SpagoBI's address instead of localhost.
If you already doing so, I see on SpagoBI troubleshooting that you should try with http://serverIP:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE.
I would check that 8080 port is open on firewall anyway.
If you have access to the GUI on server I would try to open in a browser that http://localhost:8080 is actually working at least locally.

Comment: Thanks. My local machine is windows, and I am remote connecting to the linux server which is hosting SpagoBI. The problem is I don't have access to a GUI on my sever so I can't check if localhost is actually working. I've done it before on a VM, but I need to have it on the server now.

Comment: Given that the OP has ssh access it would be easiest to use a browser with a text interface, like lynx, or just try to get the main page with wget, in order to check port 8080 on the "local machine" (where he is logged in through ssh).

Comment: With curl localhost 8080 on your server you can check it, and saw that you there check the ipaddress of the server as well (ip addr show - ifconfig). Go on windows and on the url of your browser, write http://serveripaddress:8080.
What happens?

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to reply, I've been away from this piece of work and am only getting back to it now. So I was able to access the SpagoBI on the server using the text browser. I accessed it through http://ipaddress:8080/SpagoBI , however it doesn't work on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the spagoBI is working in linux server or not. If not follow these steps: http://www.2daygeek.com/spagobi-5-0-release-notes-installation-steps/

If it's working in linux server, it can be opened in you windows system with the url:http://ipaddress of linux server:portnumber/SpagoBI.